# How to transfer entities to telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

The [official API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) has an entities parameter, but when I pass it to telebot, it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'entities'
```

Code:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'audio', 'document', 'photo'])
def messages(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=message.text, entities=message.entities)       
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=123)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

First of all bo.send_message has no attribute 'entities'
If you want to look up the entities, just try

```
print(message.entities[0])
```

it returns you this text: *{'type': 'bot_command', 'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'url': None, 'user': None, 'language': None}*

You can return multiple reply entities object using message.entities without number. By the way you can not return entities in bot.send_message command. For this you should try to use a variable or print command to look what is in the entity.

The attributes in entities:

- type
- url
- offset
- length
- user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass "**entities**" to the message you should pass first of all list of

```
MessageEntity()
```

instances, where each instance will have it's own instruction regarding the text should be sent.

As it was mentioned by [Senku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13931658/senku) the attributes are as follows:

**type** - can be "mention", "bold", "italic", " spoiler" etc.
more in [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity)

**Type** is used to give instruction which type of text will have the message given in the "text" keyword

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Here is the text to be edited by 
    entities")
```

So, for this example I will use "italic"

```
type="italic"
```

**offset** is used to denote offset from the first symbol in a text. I will use 5 for this case, so that transformation will start from 6th symbol

```
offset=5
```

**length** is used to denote how many symbols will be used after offset

```
length=6
```

Finally, my code will look as follows:

```
text_message = "Here is the text to be edited by entities"
message_entities = [MessageEntity(length=6, offset=5, type="italic")]
bot.send_message(
    chat_id=message.chat.id, 
    entities=message_entities, 
    text=text_message)
```

And the output:

" Here *is the* text to be edited by entities "

**url:** is used for “text_link” only, URL that will be opened after user taps on the text (from official documentation)

**user** is used for “text_mention” only, the mentioned user (from official documentation)

**Remember**, that *entities* work only if

```
parse_mode=None
```